# JQuery Validate - Dynamic Form Field Messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validate to do validation on my forms.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            customemail: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error'),
        lastName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'lastName').attr('data-error'),
        email: $('#email').attr('data-error')

    },
```

This works, pefectly. but now I need to make a change so that the messages object can have dynamic feild names based on a global variable so I need to do something like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
       "email": {
            customemail: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
         "myGlobalVar" + firstName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error'),
         "myGlobalVar" + lastName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'lastName').attr('data-error'),
         "myGlobalVar" + email: $('#email').attr('data-error')

    },
```

I was thinking if I create the messages object outside of this method, then I would end up with something like this, might work

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
       "email": {
            customemail: true
        }
    },
    messages: myMessageObject

    },
```

but I'm still not sure on the syntax to create a dynamic object in this way.

Ideas please?

**UPDATE:**
Chirag Ravindra Answer looked like exactly what I needed so I tired it, but it didn't work. So as a first step I tried this based on **Chirag Ravindra answer:**

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            customemail: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Prefix_firstName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error'),
        lastName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'lastName').attr('data-error'),
        email: $('#email').attr('data-error'),
        jobTitle: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'jobTitle').attr('data-error'),
        company: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'company').attr('data-error'),
        phone: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'phone').attr('data-error'),
        comments: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'comments').attr('data-error')
    },
```

This works for the Prefix_firstName field, BUT this doesn't work:

```
var validationMessages = {};

validationMessages =  {
            Prefix_firstName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error'),
            lastName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'lastName').attr('data-error'),
            email: $('#email').attr('data-error'),
            jobTitle: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'jobTitle').attr('data-error'),
            company: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'company').attr('data-error'),
            phone: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'phone').attr('data-error'),
            comments: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'comments').attr('data-error')
        },

        $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    customemail: true
                }
            },
            messages: validationMessages,
```

I really don't understand why just by moving the messages in to an object causes it to fail...

Comment: When you say `dynamic object` do you mean that the keys in that object should be dynamically prefixed using a value stored in a global variable?

Comment: Is there any element with name attribute as `"myGlobalVar" + firstName` in your html?

Comment: aren't you looking for the eval function, for instance 
eval (var "myGlobalVar"+name = "");
to create a variable myGlobalVarJohnDoe ?

Comment: Why are you trying to retrieve these attributes by an `id` that you are dynamically constructing while it's already assigned to a `name` that you know?  It would also be helpful if you showed us the relevant HTML markup for this example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is valid syntax:

```
{
     "myGlobalVar" + firstName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error'),
     "myGlobalVar" + lastName: $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'lastName').attr('data-error'),
     "myGlobalVar" + email: $('#email').attr('data-error')

}
```

You can use the array notation to create objects with dynamic keys (if that is your intention):

```js
var requestTypeValue = 'test';
var myGlobalPrefix = 'prefix_';
var myMessagesObject = {};

myMessagesObject[myGlobalPrefix+'firstname'] = $('#' + requestTypeValue + '_' + 'firstName').attr('data-error');

console.log(myMessagesObject);

/**
Output:
{
  "prefix_firstname": "Error Message"
}
**/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test_firstName' data-error="Error Message"></div>
```

You can then use the `myMessagesObject` handler in your validation method

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
       "email": {
            customemail: true
        }
    },
    messages: myMessagesObject

 },...)
```

Comment: This looks good... but I can't quite get it to work... I have updated the question... there must be a way to do this!

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? In the edits of the updated question you are using a comma after the initialisation. Change that to a semicolon and check it out.. it should work

Comment: A link to the validation plugin and a snapshot of what your DOM looks like will help debug this better. Consider creating an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the error happening live and be better equipped to reproduce the issue and debug it